# How to execute code only on exact match from array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a small filter for threads and users for a forum and I'm not able to make it run only on exact matches, for example I want to filter "car" but it also filters all words containing "car" as "cartoon", etc.

I've prepared an example thread list:

```js
var Usuarios = ["i want to select this", "this", "||"];
//I also need to use special characters

var Filtrar = document.querySelectorAll('span[onclick*="member.php?u="]');
for (var i = 0; i < Filtrar.length; i++) {
  checkToBlock(Filtrar[i], "textContent");
}
function checkToBlock(obj, namePropText) {
  var text = obj[namePropText];
  for (var i = 0; i < Usuarios.length; i++) {
    if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(Usuarios[i].toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      obj.closest("tr").style.opacity = ".5";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 32px;
}
a:link {
  color: #cc3300;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #cc3300;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  color: #330099;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

td {
  font: 10pt verdana;
}
.tborder {
  background: #D1D1D1;
  color: #000000;
  border: 0px solid #a1a1a1;
}
.alt1 {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  color: #000000;
}

.smallfont {
  font: 11px verdana;
}
```

```html
<table class="tborder" id="threadslist" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody id="threadbits_forum_12">
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0001" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0001" id="thread_title_0001">Example for special characters</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=100', '_self')">Tro||</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0002" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0002" id="thread_title_0002">Just a thread</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=100', '_self')">I want to select this</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0003" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0003" id="thread_title_0003">And</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=200', '_self')">this</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0004" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0004" id="thread_title_0004">Another thread</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=200', '_self')">NOT THIS</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0005" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0005" id="thread_title_0005">Intresting thread</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=300', '_self')">That guy</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    
    
    
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Please show only the relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to change this, which tests for "is `Usuarios[i]` in `text`":

```
if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(Usuarios[i].toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
```

to this, which tests for "is `text` equal to `Usarios[i]`":

```
if (text.toLowerCase() === Usuarios[i].toLowerCase()) {
```

Here's the fix in your snippet:

```js
var Usuarios = ["i want to select this", "this", "||"];
//I also need to use special characters

var Filtrar = document.querySelectorAll('span[onclick*="member.php?u="]');
for (var i = 0; i < Filtrar.length; i++) {
  checkToBlock(Filtrar[i], "textContent");
}
function checkToBlock(obj, namePropText) {
  var text = obj[namePropText];
  for (var i = 0; i < Usuarios.length; i++) {
    if (text.toLowerCase() === Usuarios[i].toLowerCase()) {
      obj.closest("tr").style.opacity = ".5";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 32px;
}
a:link {
  color: #cc3300;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: #cc3300;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  color: #330099;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

td {
  font: 10pt verdana;
}
.tborder {
  background: #D1D1D1;
  color: #000000;
  border: 0px solid #a1a1a1;
}
.alt1 {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  color: #000000;
}

.smallfont {
  font: 11px verdana;
}
```

```html
<table class="tborder" id="threadslist" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody id="threadbits_forum_12">
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0001" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0001" id="thread_title_0001">Example for special characters</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=100', '_self')">Tro||</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0002" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0002" id="thread_title_0002">Just a thread</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=100', '_self')">I want to select this</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0003" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0003" id="thread_title_0003">And</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=200', '_self')">this</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0004" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0004" id="thread_title_0004">Another thread</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=200', '_self')">NOT THIS</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_0005" title="">
        <div>
          <a href="showthread.php?t=0005" id="thread_title_0005">Intresting thread</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallfont">
          <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.open('member.php?u=300', '_self')">That guy</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    
    
    
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Exactly, that is what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot. Sorry for bothering with such simple questions but I'm newbie, I was searching and trying for hours before posting here. Thanks again.